# Take notes, and enter into a Google Docs spreadsheet using Google Assistant.

Tags: google-assistant

I have a pair of Google Assistant compatible headphones, and I want to use Google Assistant to help me keep track of my spending.

Essentially, I want to be able to say:

'spent $20 of groceries', or 'spent $10 on transport' etc,

and that map on to an spread sheet like:

```
datetime             type         amount
11/11/2018 5:10pm    groceries    20
12/11/2018 5:55pm    transport    10
```

I am happy to use an IFTTT integration to do this.

What would the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok,this is actually pretty simple on IFTTT - it's lucky that it's a simple task.

Here's an applet I created:

https://ifttt.com/applets/91022983d-if-you-say-spent-on-then-add-row-to-google-drive-spreadsheet

Essentially you can create a text and number trigger for google assistant, that maps nicely to creating rows on a spreadsheet.